# chart.js change label fontcolor

Tags: colors, label, chart.js

i have a chart like this example:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKeB3.jpg)

here is the code:

```
new Chart(document.getElementById("bar-chart-grouped"), {
type: 'bar',
data: {
  labels: ["1900", "1950", "1999", "2050"],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: "Africa",
      backgroundColor: "#3e95cd",
      data: [133,221,783,2478]
    }, {
      label: "Europe",
      backgroundColor: "#8e5ea2",
      data: [408,547,675,734]
    }
  ]
},
options: {
  title: {
    display: true,
    text: 'Population growth (millions)'
  }
}
```

});

This is working without problem.
What i want to do is change the fontcolor for each label, e.g Africa with fontcolor red and Europe with fonctcolor blue.

Thanks for help.

Comment: you want to change the legend font color alone?

Comment: Yes, but as i said for each label a different color in the legend.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44352402/how-to-change-the-color-of-legend-in-chartjs-and-be-able-to-add-one-more-legend